# iota-client library (python)

Tags: pyota, iota-cli, python, raspberry-pi

I am working on iota-client library ( downloaded lib from https://pypi.org/project/iota-client/#files) on my ubuntu 20.04 laptop and all go well. However when I try to install the iota-client on raspberry pi4 to interact with GPIO, it doesnt't work? Is there a way to compile the python library on rasbian core?
Thanks

Comment: Hey ajebbar.  What do you mean by "it doesn't work"?  What commands are you running, and what output are you getting?  In particular, we need to see any error messages, compilation errors, etc. that will help to diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The python wheel files you are looking for are hard to perma link.

1. Login to [github.com](https://github.com)
2. Go here: https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.rs/actions/workflows/python_binding_publish.yml
3. Click on the latest action in the list
4. Scroll to the bottom to access the latest python wheel files.

The python bindings you can also build yourself:

- source: https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.rs/tree/dev/bindings/python
- documentation: https://client-lib.docs.iota.org/libraries/python/examples.html

You can also use the node.js bindings for the iota.rs rust library, they seem to be pushing out releases for them more readily:

- Wheel Releases: https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.rs/releases
- Source: https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.rs/tree/dev/bindings/nodejs
- Documentation: https://client-lib.docs.iota.org/libraries/nodejs/examples.html

Comment: Thanks. I managed to compile the iota-lib on raspberry pi and now works fine. (import iota-lib in python)